# SQL: how to group by max date

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to SQL, so please excuse what seems like what should be basic query. I've been searching for and trying to convert other similar answer's code to make mine work, but I just can't seem to get it right.

I have 2 tables. The tables are linked via a unique Employee ID(EMPLID). Table 1(JOB) houses various job related information like title and table 2(TITLE_CHANGES) houses promotion actions, reasons, and dates. I need to develop a query that returns * from both JOB and TITLE_CHANGES tables based on the most recent TITLE_CHANGES date.

FYI this does not mirror my actual table data. I am oversimplifying it to make it easier to explain.

```
It should return:

EMLPID |     TITLE    |TitleDate   |TitleChnageReason|Requested_Date

12345  |  Specialist 2| 02/01/2015|      Merit       |01/31/2015

JOB table    
  EMPLID    |         Title       | Title Date  
---------+---------------+----------------+  
 12345      |  Specialist 2       | 02/01/2015       
--------+----------------+----------------  
 12345      |  Specialist 1       | 09/01/2014  
--------+----------------+----------------  
 44576      |  Analyst 3          | 05/01/2015  
--------+----------------+----------------  
 44576      |  Analyst 2          | 03/01/2014  
--------+---------------------+-----------  

TITLE_CHANGES Table

  EMPLID    | Title change reason | Requested_Date  
------------+---------------------+----------------+  
 12345      |  Merit              | 01/31/2015  
------------+---------------------+----------------  
 12345      |  Newhire            | 08/30/2014  
------------+---------------------+----------------  
 44576      |  Promotion          | 04/30/2015  
------------+---------------------+----------------  
 44576      |  Newhire            | 02/28/2014  
------------+---------------------+----------------
```

Thanks for your help!

Craig

Comment: Show an example of what you've tried - this is a fairly generic task.

Comment: So your real data uses date data types?

Comment: @ChrisL I cant' really show the SQL as the actual table fields are much more complex than the simplified version I gave.

Comment: @Strawberry, yes the date fields are of the "date" data type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT j.EMPLID, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(j.TITLE ORDER BY j.TitleDate DESC),',',1) AS title,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(j.TitleDate ORDER BY j.TitleDate DESC),',',1) AS title_date, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tc.TitleChnageReason ORDER BY tc.Requested_Date DESC),',',1) AS title_change_reson,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tc.Requested_Date ORDER BY tc.Requested_Date DESC),',',1) AS request_date,
FROM JOB j
JOIN TITLE_CHANGES tc ON(tc.EMPLID = j.EMPLID)
GROUP BY j.EMPLID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT j.emplid AS 'EMPLID', j.title AS 'TITLE', j.title_date AS 'TitleDate', e.reason AS 'TitleChangeReason', q.requested_date AS 'Requested_Date'
FROM
    job j
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT a.* 
        FROM title_changes a
        INNER JOIN (SELECT emplid, MAX(requested_date) as rd FROM title_changes GROUP BY 1) b 
        ON a.emplid=b.emplid AND a.requested_date=b.rd) 
    e ON j.emplid=e.emplid
```

Answer (score 0):

Select *
From job j
Inner join Title_Change tj
On j.empid = tj.empid
Order by  j.titledate desc

Comment: That's what I had initially. The problem is that this query returns ALL the EMPLID entries and puts them in order. I need ONLY the 1 entry from JOB table that corresponds with the MOST RECENT entry from TITLE_CHANGES table for each employee.

Answer (score 0):

Select Top(1) j.empid, j.title, j.titleDate,tj.TitleChangeReason,tj.Request_Date
From job j
Inner join Title_Change tj
On j.empId= tj.empid
Order by j.TitleDate desc

Try this,
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

select j.EMPLID, j.Title, j.Title Date, Title change reason , MAX(tc.Requested_Date) from JOB j, TITLE_CHANGES tc where j.EMPLID=tc.EMPLID